# ajax call error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null "

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

when i click on upload cv browse button it should call  $('#upload_resume_doc').change(function () function, but it's showing an error in console and now ajax call is not being called. i have to face this problem on all browsers.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url("resources/js`enter code here`/jquery.bonsai.js"); ?>"></script>
<div id="content-wrapper" class="container">
    <div class="advance-search-panel">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#by_cv_matches">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="pull-left"> <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url("resources/images/search-image-cv.jpg"); ?>"  alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h3 class="media-heading">Search Jobs with CV Matches</h3>
                                Match Jobs Using Skills in Your CV. </div>
                        </div>
                    </a> 
                </div>

                <div id="by_cv_matches" class="panel-collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-inline" action="<?php echo base_url('job/search'); ?>" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-8">
                                <!-- Display filename inside the button instead of its label -->
                                <input id="upload_resume_doc" name="document" type="file" class="input-lg col-lg-12 text-left" data-filename-placement="inside" title="Upload CV - Browse">
                                <div id="loading"></div>
                                <div id="ext_keywords" style=" margin-top: 50px;"><lable><h4>Extracted keywords from your CV</h4></lable>
                                    Here are extracted keywords from your CV, <br>You can add or remove keywords from extracted keywords.
                                <textarea  type="text" id="keywords" name="keywords" onkeynpress="getJobId(id);" value="" placeholder="Enter the Message" rows="6" cols="65"/></textarea>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <select name="jobIndustry" class="form-control input-lg" style="width:300px">
                                    <option value="">Select Industry</option>
                                    <?php foreach ($job_industries as $job) { ?>
                                        <optgroup label="<?php echo ucwords($job->name) ?>">
                                            <?php if (!empty($job->subcategories)) { ?>
                                                <?php foreach ($job->subcategories as $sub) { ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $sub->id; ?>"><?php echo ucwords($sub->name) ?></option>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </optgroup>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                                <div class="form-group" class="input-lg col-lg-12 text-left" style="width: 500px;">
                                        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="main_search_minimumSalary" placeholder="Minimum Salary" name="minimumSalary">  -->

                                            <label>Job Type</label><br>
                                            <select name="jobtype" id="jobtype"  style="width: 265px; height: 35px;" onchange="showHideSalaryType();">
                                                <option value="">Select Job Type</option>
                                                <option value="Permanent" <?php echo set_select('jobtype', 'Permanent'); ?> >Permanent</option>
                                                <option value="Part-Time" <?php echo set_select('jobtype', 'Part-Time'); ?> >Part-Time</option>
                                                <option value="Contract" <?php echo set_select('jobtype', 'Contract'); ?> >Contract</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                    <div class="col-lg-12" id="parmanent">
                                        <h4 class="text-blue" >PER ANNUM</h4>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-inline">
                                                <label>From</label>
                                                <input href="javascript:void(0)" type="text" name="min_salary" value="<?php echo set_value('min_salary'); ?>" placeholder="Minimum Salary" class="form-control input-lg" style="width: 210px;">
                                                <label style="margin-left: 20px;">to </label>
                                                <input href="javascript:void(0)" type="text" name="max_salary" value="<?php echo set_value('max_salary'); ?>" placeholder="Maximum Salary" class="form-control input-lg" style="width: 230px; margin-left: 30px;">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12" id="perday" style="display: none;">
                                        <h4 class="text-blue">PER DAY SALARY</h4>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-inline">
                                                <label>From</label>
                                                <input href="javascript:void(0)" type="text" name="min_salary_day" value="<?php echo set_value('min_salary_day'); ?>" placeholder="Minimum Salary" class="form-control input-lg" style="width: 210px;">
                                                <label style="margin-left: 20px;">to </label>
                                                <input href="javascript:void(0)" type="text" name="max_salary_day" value="<?php echo set_value('max_salary_day'); ?>" placeholder="Maximum Salary" class="form-control input-lg" style="width: 230px; margin-left: 30px;">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12" id="perhour" style="display: none;">
                                        <h4 class="text-blue">PER HOUR SALARY</h4>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="form-inline">
                                                <label>From</label>
                                                <input href="javascript:void(0)" type="text" name="min_salary_hour" value="<?php echo set_value('min_salary_hour'); ?>" placeholder="Minimum Salary" class="form-control input-lg" style="width: 210px;">
                                                <label style="margin-left: 20px;">to </label>
                                                <input href="javascript:void(0)" type="text" name="max_salary_hour" value="<?php echo set_value('max_salary_hour'); ?>" placeholder="Maximum Salary" class="form-control input-lg" style="width: 230px; margin-left: 30px;">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
</div>

                            <button type="submit" id="search" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-search"></span> SEARCH</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#by_Industry_Sector">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="pull-left"> <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url("resources/images/industry-sector.jpg"); ?>"  alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h3 class="media-heading">Search Jobs by Industry Sector</h3>
                                Search Job in a Particular Industry Sector or Sub Sector </div>
                        </div>
                    </a> 
                </div>
                <div id="by_Industry_Sector" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('job/search');?>">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="jobIndustry" class="form-control input-lg" style="width:500px">
                                    <option value="">Select Industry</option>
                                    <?php foreach ($job_industries as $job) { ?>
                                        <optgroup label="<?php echo ucwords($job->name) ?>">
                                            <?php if (!empty($job->subcategories)) { ?>
                                                <?php foreach ($job->subcategories as $sub) { ?>
                                                    <option value="<?php echo $sub->id; ?>"><?php echo ucwords($sub->name) ?></option>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </optgroup>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>

                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-search"></span> SEARCH</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#by_Location">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="pull-left"> <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo base_url("resources/images/search-by-location.jpg"); ?>"  alt=""> </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h3 class="media-heading">Search Jobs by Location</h3>
                                Find All Jobs Within an area in UK </div>
                        </div>
                    </a> 
                </div>




                <div id="by_Location" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-inline" role="form"  method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('job/search');?>">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="area" class="form-control input-lg" id="area"  style="width:500px" placeholder="LOCATION">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-yellow"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-search"></span> SEARCH</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url("resources/js/file.uploader.js"); ?>"></script>-->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url("resources/js/file.uploader.js"); ?>"></script>
<!--<script>
    //    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#upload_resume_doc").change(function() {

        ajaxFileUploader("#upload_resume_doc", {
            alert('sssssss');
            url: base_url + 'uploader/upload_and_search_keywords',
            loader: '#uploadProcess2',
            data: {
                doc_name: $("#document_name_id").val()
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    var ext = response.data.ext;
                    var icon;
                    if (ext == '.doc' || ext == '.docx') {
                        icon = 'doc-icon.png';
                    } else if (ext == '.xls' || ext == '.xlsx') {
                        icon = 'excel-icon.png';
                    } else if (ext == '.pdf') {
                        icon = 'pdf-icon.png';
                    }
                    if (response.keywords == "" || response.keywords == ",") {
                        displayUIMessage(response.message);
                    } else {
                        $('#main_search_Keyword').val(response.keywords);
                        $('#mainSubmitButton').click();
                    }
                   $('#AuctionDocumentsList').append(imgHtml);


                } else {
                    displayUIMessage(response.message);
                }
                $("#document_name_id").val('');
            }
        });
    });
    //    });

</script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#upload_resume_doc").change(function() {

        ajaxFileUploader("#upload_resume_doc", {

            url: base_url + 'uploader/upload_and_search_keywords',
//             alert('adsfasfas');
            loader: '#uploadProcess2',
            data: {
                doc_name: $("#document_name_id").val()
            },
            success: function(response) {

                console.log(response);
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    var ext = response.data.ext;
                    var icon;
                    if (ext == '.doc' || ext == '.docx') {
                        icon = 'doc-icon.png';
                    } else if (ext == '.xls' || ext == '.xlsx') {
                        icon = 'excel-icon.png';
                    } else if (ext == '.pdf') {
                        icon = 'pdf-icon.png';
                    }
                    if (response.keywords == "" || response.keywords == ",") {
                        displayUIMessage(response.message);

                } else {
                    displayUIMessage(response.message);
                }
                $("#document_name_id").val('');
            }
        });
    });


</script>
 <script>

    $('#upload_resume_doc').change(function () {
    // add loading image to div
    $('#loading').html('<img `enter code here`src="http://preloaders.net/preloaders/287/Filling%20broken%20ring.gif"> loading...');
    // run ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",`enter code here`
        dataType: "json",
        url: "https://api.github.com/users/jveldboom",
        success: function () {
//            console.log(msg) 
            // replace div's content with returned data
            // $('#loading').html('<img src="'+d.avatar_url+'"><br>'+d.login);
            // setTimeout added to show loading
            setTimeout(function () {
//                $('#loading').html('<img src="' +  + '"><br>' + d.login);
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
            </script>

            <script>
    function showHideSalaryType() {
        var dropDownValue = document.getElementsByName('jobtype'); //will be an array
        var result = dropDownValue[0].options[dropDownValue[0].selectedIndex].value;
        if (result === 'Part-Time' || result === 'Contract') {
            $("#parmanent").hide();
            $("#perday").show();
            $("#perhour").show();
        } else {
            $("#parmanent").show();
            $("#perday").hide();
            $("#perhour").hide();
        }
    }

</script>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back and read the jQuery docs.  response, the first parameter passed to your success, is the text response from the server (or transposed into some other form like json).  The SECOND parameter, is the textstatus.  The third parameter is the jqXHR request.

Your first parameter will NEVER have a "status" unless you are making that part of the json you are returning, which I doubt.

Secondly, $.ajax success only gets called on a status of 200, so your check is meaningless.

But since I don't see the code for "ajaxfileuploader" the above may be irrelevant